# NestJS/TypeORM: Add url to cors origin while application in running

Tags: cors, nestjs, typeorm

I made NestJs API in which urls for cors origin are stored in database (and it works). Anyways after adding new url, I need to restart the API for this cors origin list to update... is it possible to add something to it without need to restart the application?

my main.js:

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import * as express from 'express';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { ConnectedApps } from './models/connectedApps.model';


async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
    AppModule,
  );

  const connectedApps = await app.get(Connection).getRepository(ConnectedApps).find();
  let origin = connectedApps.map(a => { return a.apiUrl });

  app.enableCors({origin: [ 
    ...origin
  ]});

  await app.listen(3178);
}
bootstrap();
```

I was also thinking about something like auto restart after adding new url. In main.js it would be like `app.close()` & `app.listen(1234)`, but how to call a restart from a service?

@Edit:
I have found this solution for shutdown and it works (but for shutdown only). [How to trigger application shutdown from a service in Nest.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146395/how-to-trigger-application-shutdown-from-a-service-in-nest-js)
I tried to replace the function on subscribe in main.js to

```js
{
  await app.close();
  await app.listen(3178); // also app.init(), this.bootstrap();
}
```

But I still can't start the app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have found ideal solution for my problem

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import * as express from 'express';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { ConnectedApps } from './models/connectedApps.model';
import { SystemService } from './system/system.service';


async function bootstrap() {
  let app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
    AppModule,
  );

  init(app);
}
bootstrap();

async function init(app: any) {
  const connectedApps = await 
  app.get(Connection).getRepository(ConnectedApps).find();
  let origin = connectedApps.map(a => { return a.appUrl });

  app.enableCors({origin: [
    ...origin
  ]});

  await app.listen(3178);

  app.get(SystemService).subscribeToRestart(async () => {
    await app.close();

    app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
      AppModule,
    );
    init(app);    
  });
}
```